# Written correct code in Unity C# , but not getting expected output

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written the folowing code (given below) -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        transform.position += Vector3.right;
}
}
```

According the the code, the sprite needs to move right when right arrow is pressed. But the sprite is not moving. So what is wrong in the code?

Note- I am using Unity version 5.4

Comment: You use on key down and it moves by 1. Try with Input.GetKey and transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed; Remember to create and give a value to speed other than 0.

Comment: Please use the correct tags. `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like language used in previous Unity versions and is long deprecated by now. Your code is clearly `c#`. Also your question is quite unclear. Please explain exactly what you would expect vs what happens instead. In general: If your code does not what it is supposed to then it is extremely questionable that it is written correctly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html), you can't hold the key pressed, you have to press it over and over again.

Then, as Everts mentioned, you should always include Time.deltaTime in your calculation to avoid issues when your application is lagging for whatever reason.

So you need two steps:

1. Use Everts' suggestion `transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed;` and try to figure out how big speed might be. It might be anywhere from: 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 up to 1, 10, 100 etc, whatever suits you. But this formula will prevent a lot of issues in the future.
2. Use [Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html) instead of Input.KeyKeyDown